# How to set Textview , Edittext and button height's to be same on Linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

How I can set the `LinearLayout` items height's to same. I tried with `RelativeLayout` but can get any success. Any idea how I can do it ? Tyvm for any help

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:weightSum="11">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblParca"

        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5.5"
        android:text="Parça Kodu"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txthldMalzemeKodu"
        style="@style/DefaultEditTextSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnhldgetMalzeme"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_ara" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That's what I got:

[image]

Comment: set value for the height?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Tell me what do you need and i'll provide you the good `XML file`

Comment: The most straight forward way is to set fixed heights for everything (i.e. `android:layout_height = "56dp"` (may also need tweak the `gravity` and `layout_gravity`)

Comment: i dont want to set Hardcoded height , any other ideA ?

Comment: Yes, but... where you need your elements... I don't know...

Comment: You will likely need a custom view for your container layout, have it measure it's children to see which is the "tallest" and then stretch the other views to match that height.

Comment: to Aspicas " I need something like this" http://tinypic.com/r/2whi4ht/9

Comment: You can tag people with the @[username] syntax

Comment: @CanAltunoz ahh okay, let me make you a new `XML file`

Comment: @zgc70009 tyvm i wasnt know how to do it

Comment: I believe @zgc7009 has the correct approach. I'd create a class the extends `LinearLayout` and override `onMeasure()`. There I'd set the height of the `ViewGroup` and the other child views based on the height of its largest child - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with Aspicas answer, the layout can be simplified to just

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblParca"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:text="Parça Kodu" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txthldMalzemeKodu"
        style="@style/DefaultEditTextSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnhldgetMalzeme"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_ara"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

There is no need to have all of the wrappers. Also notice the change to your TextView utilizing `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity` to center your content. I am actually surprised this works, from my understanding this should be stretching the height of the views, apparently I was wrong in that thinking.

Comment: You have right, There is no need to have all of the wrappers, but usually you need modify your design inside `Linear_Layouts` then if you don't have inside another `LinearLay` you will have to modify all the elements, in this way, if you need modify something, you just have to change inside the `LinearLayout` you need, without modifying anothers but... yes, your answer surely works too.

Comment: @Aspicas you aren't wrong, but you should avoid implementing extraneous code until you need it. If at any point some of the content needs a wrapper, it's an easy enough fix to avoid having the wrappers when you don't need them. You aren't wrong, and I'm not necessarily right, it's just how you want to manage your code.

Comment: Okay,  Thanks for your time. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use  `android:layout_weight="1"` for all views, and set `android:layout_height="0"`

[Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) on documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this `xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="11">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblParca"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Parça Kodu"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txthldMalzemeKodu"
                style="@style/DefaultEditTextSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnhldgetMalzeme"
                style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_ara"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tyvm Aspicas thats it

Comment: I'm glad to listen. No problem, any question.. i'm here. @CanAltunoz

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up the same height for all the views.
Either you do this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

or

```
 android:layout_height="some value"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hardcode the Parent's LinearLayout Height .

Other way is to take 3 Linear Layout for each of the items & in each LinearLayout 
 set

```
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```